# C# Convert int to string and use in a Label

Tags: c#, int

I have the following scenario.I am using App.config in Winforms and I have a value that is set to int (In settings).  I want to use this value as a label text.
Am I correct that labels can only display string values?
This is what I have done here but not getting expected result (value to the label):

```
        int ExclRate = Properties.Settings.Default.PriorExclTimer;
        string ExclTime = ExclRate.ToString();
        ExclTime = label60.Text;
```

PriorExclTimer is the type of the value in app.config.

I can make this work if I set the value in app.config to string, but that means I would have to convert from string to int in a much more sensitive part of the program, and I would rather not have to do that if possible.  This is that line that works:

```
         label60.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.PriorExclTimer;
```

I'm very new to C#, so I am really feeling my way around.  Thanks...

Comment: It's a bit strange, you ask how to convert a property to assign to a label, while you do the other way around (assign a property from a label text)?

Comment: You can either use label60 = ExclRate .ToString() or ExclRate .ToString(formatstring) or simply ExclRate + ""

Comment: Yes sorry.  Here is the line that works as string:             label60.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.PriorExclTimer;  Looking this over thanks for your replies

Answer (score 3):

In C# you cannot directly assign `int` to `string`. It has to always undergo conversion (either parse string to integer, or get a string out of integer).

As you say it's better to convert integer to a string for display purposes. Labels cannot directly show integer, so you will always need to convert it, or write some wrapper class if it's not enough.

Be aware that `ToString()` is culture specific, i.e. it will use the culture from the current thread. It might or might not be what you want. If you want `InvariantCulture` you can use `ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`.

P.S. As mentioned in the comments you can do various tricks like `ExclRate + ""`, or in C#6 `${ExclRate}`, but they are all basically converting an integer to string. I guess they all call `ToString()` inside.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
int ExclRate = Properties.Settings.Default.PriorExclTimer;
label60.Text = ExclRate.ToString();
```

Many thanks for the insights on this topic.  I will be manipulating data to and from a string a good bit for the project I am working on...

Answer (score 0):

```
int ExclRate = Properties.Settings.Default.PriorExclTimer;
label60.Text = ExclRate.ToString();
```

Code above will give you exception if `PriorExclTimer` is null or empty. So better you use `int.TryParse` to assign it to int. Not in this case, but `ToString` does not handle the `null` case, it gives exception. So you should try `Convert.ToString` instead.
While doing string manipulations you have to take care of culture and case (string case sensitive or insensitive)